# MS Teams - a_target attribute in HTML is ignored in integrated sharepoint websitesites

Tags: html, sharepoint, microsoft-teams

I integrated a sharepoint websitesite into MS Teams.

Inside the sharepoint websitesite i am using HTML / CSS code for formatting the pages (-> modern script editor plugin).

In these pages i defined `a_target = _SELF` for every link to prevent, that a new page gets opened, as soon as someone clicks at an implemented link or button (although that should already be the default behaviour)

But actually, if someone clicks at one of the links, a new brower window gets opened with the content. Inside this browser window, the attribute `a_target = _SELF` works like expected.

*How can i define, that after clicking an `<a>` element, the user stays inside the corresponding MS Teams channel (in which the page is integrated)?*

`a_target = _SELF` only works AFTER the page already got reopened in a new browser window (outside the MS Teams environment).

Every idea is highly appreciated, because i actually ran out of ideas, how to solve that!

**@Hilton Giesenow:**

Basically i´ve build up a nested image container in the `<body>` of the HTML. Here is the reduced example, without sharepoint links:

```
<div class="imageContainer">

    <div class="iconContainer1">

        <a target="_self" href="https://...">
            <img id="elem1" src="https://... I1.jpg">
        </a>
        <a target="_self" href="https://...">
            <img id="elem2" src="https://... I2.jpg">
        </a>
        <a target="_self" href="https://...">
            <img id="elem3" src="https://... I3.jpg">
        </a>
        <a target="_self" href="https://...">
            <img id="elem4" src="https://... I4.jpg">
        </a>
        <a target="_self" href="https://...">
            <img id="elem5" src="https://... I5.jpg">
        </a>
        
    </div>

   <img name="elem0" src="https://... I0.jpg">

    <div class="iconContainer2">

        <a target="_self" href="https://...">
            <img id="elem6" src="https://... I6.jpg">
        </a>
        <a target="_self" href="https://...">
            <img id="elem7" src="https://... I7.jpg">
        </a>
        <a target="_self" href="https://...">
            <img id="elem8" src="https://... I8.jpg">
        </a>
        <a target="_self" href="https://...">
            <img id="elem9" src="https://... I9.jpg">
        </a>
        <a target="_self" href="https://...">
            <img id="elem10" src="https://... I10.jpg">
        </a>   
    </div>
</div>
```

**Appearance:**

[image]

Comment: Can you please give an -exact- example of how you're setting `a_target = _SELF`? Is it `<a target="_self" ...` ?